# Storing result of query in hive variable

Tags: hive

In Hive,how to store the results of a query in a variable?
I've tried the below command:
SET hivevar:a=(Query);

But instead of the result,query itself is getting stored.
Is there any way for storing the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive variables are nothing but a text replacement mechanism.
The replacement is done before parsing and execution.

```
hive> set hivevar:v1=se;
hive> set hivevar:v2=l;
hive> set hivevar:v3=ec;
hive> set hivevar:v4=t 1+;
hive> set hivevar:v5=2;
hive> ${hivevar:v1}${hivevar:v2}${hivevar:v3}${hivevar:v4}${hivevar:v5};
OK
3
```

Passing a query result as an argument to another query can be done from the shell, e.g. -

```
hive --hivevar x=$(hive -e 'select 1+2') -e 'select ${hivevar:x}*100'
```

Comment: I have a table which I have to validate.. After validation,if the number of valid records are more than a threshold value, table will be used for analysis.
else table will be rejected.
So I thought of counting the records of original table, and that of the valid table. 

Then the difference is compared to the threshold value. 
How do I do that in hive??