# How to replace hyphen (dash) in table name?

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have a hive table, where I want to replace the hyphen ('-') with underscore ('_'). 
The sample query is as:

```
CREATE TABLE test_${yearAndMonth} ......
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_${yearAndMonth} ......
```

The 'yearAndMonth' contains value like: 2017-05; So, I want to have the table value name as test_2017_05; however, the 'yearAndMonth' will must contain the hyphen value.

I have tried with: regex replace
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_${regexp_replace(yearAndMonth, '-', '_')} ......
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_${regexp_replace(yearAndMonth, '-', '_')} ......
```

However, I am getting error as:
*cannot recognize input near 'test_' '$' '{' in table na*me

Any suggestions please.

**Update:**
Trying in this was way:

```
CREATE TABLE test_regexp_replace(${yearAndMonth}, "-", "_") ......
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_regexp_replace(${yearAndMonth}, "-", "_") ......
```

I am getting this error:
*missing EOF at '(' near 'test_regexp_replace'*

Comment: **(1)** You have a misconception of what Hive variables are. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887401/storing-result-of-query-in-hive-variable/42887453#42887453. **(2)** You have to pass the variables in the right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variable format in hive is not a good idea, try to change the format before passing. Doing something similar to below will work (added id int as a sample column, you can add your own or pass them from another variable if required)

```
hive  --hiveconf table_name=table_$(date '+%Y')_$(date '+%m') -e "create table \${hiveconf:table_name}(id int); insert overwrite table \${hiveconf:table_name}"
```