# Hive: Set current year/month/day as a variable and use to define filename

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to write a file to s3 the name of which should contain current year day and month. To do this I want to define variables to get year, month and day

```
set year=year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
set month=month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
set day=day(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (col1 int, col2 varchar(100), col3 INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION "s3://location_${hiveconf:year}${hiveconf:month}${hiveconf:day}/"
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

If I run the script - 'select "${hiveconf:year}";'
I get 'year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))' as output.

Is there any other way to include day, month and year in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the set command will never evaluate a function, thats why it's returning the string the way it is.

see this for more info:  [How to store the output of a query in a variable in HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159544/how-to-store-the-output-of-a-query-in-a-variable-in-hive)

One recommendation is to use shell to capture the date and then pass that through as a parameter to your sql script.